# Unexpected performance impact of an HTTP proxy in Mule

Tags: mule

when i'm testing my project in soapui,which link directly to the wsdl can reach 1000tps or more, but  when i changed to use a http endpoints to proxy the request, the tps sharply down to 500 even less.

I don't know why, Any advice will be help.

Here is the souce code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:pattern="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern"
        xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern *http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/current/mule-pattern.xsd
*http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http *http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
*http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf *http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd
*http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans *http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
*http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core *http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
*http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking *http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
    <configuration doc:name="Configuration">  
        <default-dispatcher-threading-profile   
            maxThreadsActive="250" maxThreadsIdle="500" threadWaitTimeout="1000" threadTTL="60000" />  
        <default-receiver-threading-profile   
            maxThreadsActive="250" maxThreadsIdle="500" threadWaitTimeout="1000" threadTTL="60000" />  
        <default-service-threading-profile   
            maxThreadsActive="250" maxThreadsIdle="500" threadWaitTimeout="1000" threadTTL="60000" />              
    </configuration>  

    <flow name="CopyofmytestFlow1" doc:name="CopyofmytestFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="<a href="http://localhost:18081&quot;">http://localhost:18081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://192.168.80.27:8080/OIP-SIMU-01/services/OipServer"  doc:name="respnse" method="POST" >
        <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">

                            <add-message-property key="SOAPAction" value="#[header:inbound:SOAPAction]"/>  
                        </message-properties-transformer>
        </http:outbound-endpoint>        
    </flow>
</mule>
```

The environment:

- mule-standalone-3.4.0
- red hat enterprise linux 5
- mule studio 3.4
- soapui 4.5.2

Comment: Can you clarify what change did you made that decreased the tps?

Comment: An impact on performance is expected, naturally, but this seems too high indeed. How many concurrent load injectors do you use? What's the verbosity level of Mule, i.e. is it spitting a lot in the logs while under load? If you connect to the JVM over JMX, how many active threads do you see under load?

Comment: In soapui I set the concurrent load in 200 threads，and the log standard was set in error. Thank you for your help